# Почему substr() изменяет данные?

Tags: php, binary

Думал, ф-я `substr()` – binary safe. Столкнулся с неприятностью:

```
<?php   
$bin = 0b00001101;  // 13 - ASCII Carriage return
$c = substr($bin, 0, 1);    // читаем этот байт
printf("Ожидание: 00001101, реальность: %08b\n", $c); // 00000001
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/UfM2QG). ЧЯДНТ?

**Upd.** Разобрался ([помогли](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31850905/556876)). Надо четко разделять, где строка/символ, а где целое. Так работает:

```
$bin = 0b00001101;
$c = substr(chr($bin), 0, 1);
printf("Ожидание: 00001101, реальность: %08b\n", ord($c)); // 00001101
```

Comment: Кто заменил строку  $bin = 0x0000110100000000; на $bin = 0b00001101; ?

Comment: @Visman я заменил. 0x.. по ошибке написал.

Comment: Это не решение проблемы. Попробуйте  $bin = 0b0000110100000001;
$c = substr(chr($bin), 1, 1); Увидите не то что надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В строке

```
$bin = 0b00001101;  // 13 - ASCII Carriage return
```

$bin принимает значение 13 (в 10ой системе счисления) или '13' (как строка). В результате `substr($bin, 0, 1)` берет первый символ из строки и он равен `1`.

Чтобы работало как вы задумали, надо двоичное число по-байтно переводить в символы и по-символьно записывать в строку.

P.S. В обновлении у вас решение для частного случая.

Comment: В чем частность случая?  `chr()` и `ord()` – всё, что нужно.

Comment: Пока в $bin у вас записан 1 байт, то будет работать. Если вы запишите в $bin уже 2 байта и попробуете считать 2й символ, то работать правильно перестанет.

Comment: вот же, [например](http://ideone.com/PvnDBq), работает, как надо.

Comment: Конечно работает, потому что там вы строите строку по-символьно, преобразовывая каждый байт в символ и подставляя его в готовую строку с символами имеющими коды = 0. Так я это и написал в ответе своем.

Answer (score 1):

потому что `str` в названии функции - это сокращение от `string`
что как бы говорит нам, что эта функция работает со **строками**
перводя аргумент в понятный себе формат

```
var_dump((string)$bin);
```

Comment: `str` есть и в названии, скажем, [`strcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strcmp.php), чья документация нам прямо говорит, что эта ф-я бинарно-безопасна (*binary-safe*).